# Different behavior after putting ENT_HTML5 parameter in htmlentities

Tags: php, html-entities

This was my code for making words with a "#" at the beginning clickable:

```
$value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
preg_replace("/#([\pL\pN.]+)/u", "<span onclick='opn(event, ".$value.", \"\\1\");'>\\0</span>", $value);
```

After putting `ENT_HTML5` to the end of the second parameter in `htmlentities`:

```
htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')
```

Words with a "#" at the beginning are not clickable anymore. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> php> var_dump(htmlentities('#foo',ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
> string(4) "#foo"
> php> var_dump(htmlentities('#foo',ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'));
> string(8) "&num;foo"
> ```

Hopefully this answers your question: the regex doesn't replace your text because it doesn't match any more.

Comment: So what can i do in this situation ? is htmlentities without ENT_HTML5 as save as with ENT_HTML5 ?

Comment: i reversed the escape with str_replace (from &num; to #) and now everythin is fine. i hope there is no security issue in doing that